# Method overriding: same argument list types (or COMPATIBLE types)?

Tags: java, overriding, open-closed-principle

In the book I use to prepare for the new Oracle Certified Professional - Java SE7 Programmer exam, in the section that deals with method overriding, I have come across the following:

> The overriding method should have *the same argument list types* (*or
>   compatible types*) as the base version.

What do they mean by "compatible types"? I mean, as soon as the argument list types differ, you're overloading, not overriding.

I can only think of overriding a method that takes varargs arguments, with one that takes an array of the same type. Compiler gives a warning, but compiles still.

What do they mean by compatible types? Is that an error in the book?

Comment: Do they mean `sub`/`super` classes to the original type?

Comment: May be they mean the difference between `(int a ,String b)` and `(String b, int a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with type erasure. This is valid Java, it just gives you a warning:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public abstract void method(List<String> xs);
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void method(List xs) {
    }
}
```

The raw type `List` is compatible with `List<String>`.

Comment: IMO the most legit answer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html